# Word マクロ実行時に「応答なし」となり、ハングする。（リモートデスクトップ時は正常に動く）

Tags: oracle, ms-word, rdp

お世話になっております。

質問のタイトルの通り、Wordでマクロを実行すると結果が返されず、プログラムが「応答なし」でフリーズしてしまいます。

状況は以下の通りです。

- マクロを使用してOracleデータベースから値を取得し、テキストファイルを作成します。 テキストファイルの値を別の新しいブックにコピーし、帳票を作成します。
- マクロ付きのファイル拡張子: .doc
- 遠隔操作（リモートデスクトップ）では正常に動作します。 ⇒ここが一番不可解な部分です
- Officeを修復したり、Windows Updateを行ったりしましたが、変化はありませんでした。
- 各バージョン OS：Windows 10 Pro 22H2 Office：Microsoft Office Standard 2019

上記の状況でも書きましたが、リモートでPCに接続して操作してみると、帳票は問題なく綺麗に作成されているので、原因が分かりません。 他の人では動いていますし、リモートデスクトップ接続で操作しても動いているので、マクロが原因ではないと思います。 他に考えられる原因や解決策がありましたら、教えてください。

以下のことを試しました。

- Office、office2019のアクセス権⇒フルコントロールの付与
  　⇒対応後、リモートデスクトップで出力できるようになりましたが、永田さんが操作すると出力されません。
- クリップボード履歴OFF ⇒ 元々はOFFでした
- Officeの修復
- WindowsUpdate⇒最新
  上記の解決策を実施しましたが、ユーザーがマクロを実行した場合にのみ機能しません。 （リモートデスクトップを使ってこちら側から操作すると問題なく帳票が出力されます。）

Comment: 動かないと行っているユーザーとリモートデスクトップで接続したときのユーザーは同じユーザーですか？違っている場合、同じユーザーでリモートデスクトップでログインする、または、リモートデスクトップで接続したときのユーザーで通常のログインをした場合、現象はどうなりますか？(リモートデスクトップが原因か、ユーザーが原因かの切り分けをするために必要な情報です。)

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでの「クローズ」は、他の人が「回答する価値がない質問」として評価したときにつけられるものであり、質問者が自分でクローズすることはできません。タイトルや質問文にクローズと言う言葉を含めないでください。単に質問を終わらせたい場合は、[質問を自分から終了したい場合には?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2634)を参照してください。

Answer (score 2):

情報が不足してるのとおそらく順を追って切り分けが必要なのでQ&Aで解決するのは難しい質問だと思います。

- 同じユーザーが別PCを使う、または同PCで別ユーザーが操作するとどうなるか
- 動かないマクロ・動くマクロがあるのか、動かないマクロの一部を切り出すとどうなるのか
- マクロ付きファイルの置き場所やファイルの出力先を変えるとどうなるか

などなど、関係しそうな要素を網羅的に調べて結果をマトリックスにして記載してもらえば回答がでるかもしれませんが、多分そこまでやったら自ずと原因がわかるでしょう。または原因を調べるよりさっさとPCの再セットアップやユーザーの作り直しをした方が早いかもしれません。

Comment: 本件は解決しましたので、クローズします。